# Bash Variables Access Between TMUX Sessions

Tags: bash, variables, tmux

I want to have variables that are accessible in between tmux sessions in bash.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  Do you want variables that if you update in one session you see the change in another, or that when you start a new session you'll see a set of variables that you preconfigured, or that when you start a new session you'll see the last values of some variables from a previous session?  Better still, what are you actually hoping to accomplish--because variables are perhaps not the best way to accomplish it (or even possible depending on what you really want).

Comment: @EricRenouf xyz problem I see :P

I have a program which runs over and over in a tmux session. Whenever it stops it autorestarts. I want to be able to set a variable that tells it to not autorestart so that next time it stops it wont start again.

Comment: Could you just have it look for the existence of a flag file on disk instead of the value in a variable?  Then you could just `touch` the file from anywhere.

Comment: @EricRenouf That is actually a genius idea, thank you!